# When answers are the same but the evidence is different

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67604/book-identification-borrowing-minds-of-animals) has recieved two answers that are essentially the same - book identification pointing to the same book [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/67614/20533) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/67619/20533).  I was ready to flag the later answer as a duplicate, until I read the content of the answer, and realized it was providing an entirely different (and valid) set of evidence for this answer.

Now I'm puzzled - the answers essentially point to the same answer to the question as a whole, but come to the conclusion in entirely different but completely valid ways.

Should I suggest an edit to one of the answers?   Should I flag one as a duplicate?   Should I mark one to be added to another in some way?  And if so, should the asker who provided these new details be rewarded for their effort, since they DID provide an answer that was independent of the other, despite pointing to the same source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Answers* are never flagged as duplicates — questions can be.

Answers can be voted on. If both answers are of value, vote both up. It's up to the Asker to accept one of them.